# Limit-Concept about a fundamental principle of limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

It is said that in $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ .

f(x) should be greater than 0.
Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: I claim (I've been told this isn't right, so take it for what it's worth), that $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is, by definition, $e^{x\log(f(x))}$, for all $x$ is the intersection of the domains of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: your question is missing frame-work

Comment: Perhaps the point you're missing is that if $f(x)<0$ for values of $x$ as $x\to a$, it is likely that $f(x)^{g(x)}$ will not even be defined. (For example, how do you define $(-1)^{1/2}$?)

Comment: I forgot to say that $x$ should be positive.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a condition for the rewriting
$$ \tag{?} \lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = \Bigl(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\Bigr)^{\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)} $$
to work.

The reason why this needs extra conditions is that if $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to0$, then knowing these limits is not enough to know what the limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is (or if it exists at all).

It happens that *if* that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) > 0$, then (?) does work.

Likewise, if $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) > 0$ (and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ge 0$), then (?) also works.

However simply having $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ is *not* enough. In that case it is still possible that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both go to $0$ in ways that can make $f(x)^{g(x)}$ have any limit, or none.

The underlying reason is that the function $x,y\mapsto x^y$ is *not continuous* at $(0,0)$ -- no matter whether we consider $0^0$ to be undefined or define $0^0=1$.